# change where Authoring information and Publishing options Checkbox is displayed

Tags: 7, views, blocks, nodes

Currently Authoring information and Publishing options have options within their own how do you call it "tab/page". Example: When you edit a page you have to click Publishing options in order to see the **checkbox Published**.

I want that checkbox Published + it's functionality when checked somewhere else within the edit content page.

So there is no step where you have to click Publishing options. Should I do this with a custom block?

Can anyone assist because I really don't know how to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the admin/content page 
1. at the top there is filters provided to sort content by number of options like for e.g filter by content type, published or unpublished.
2. then below that there is drop down containing list of actions like "publish selected content", "delete selected content", etc
3.You can select the check box corresponding to the content you want the action to perform and submit.

Comment: I know you can do that there but how do I get that into 1 checkbox on my edit page of a content type?